# Cannot find data format in registry - Camel

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, apache-camel

I have a maven project, and I'm trying to marshal a file using jaxb and camel with the command:

```
from("file://...").marshal("myDataFormat").to("file://...");
```

When I run the project, I get the following error:

```
Cannot find data format in registry with ref: myDataFormat
```

First, does anyone know what the "registry" is? I've searched Google, but can't find anything. I'm guessing it might be another name for the camel-context file. Second, how can I register a data format using camel? Is there a default data format that I can use?

Sorry if the answer is simple, but I'm relatively new to camel and the online docs that I can find haven't been too helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use something like this

```
DataFormat jaxb = new JaxbDataFormat("com.acme.model");

from("activemq:My.Queue").
      unmarshal(jaxb).
      to("mqseries:Another.Queue");
```

In other words, first create dataformat object then try to unmarshal it.

Answer (score 1):

About Camel registry http://camel.apache.org/registry.html

For simple, test task **Simple registry**  will be fine.

**Spring** or **Blueprint** is good for more complex tasks. http://camel.apache.org/using-osgi-blueprint-with-camel.html , http://camel.apache.org/spring.html , http://camel.apache.org/data-format.html (see Spring example below page)

Blueprint context example, with some data formats.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint
    xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation=
            "http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">

    <camelContext id="camelTest"
                  xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" >
        <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="blueprint:server.placeholder"/>
        <package>camel.test</package>

        <dataFormats>
            <beanio id="cashWarrantFormat" mapping="beanio/mapping.xml" streamName="CashWarrant" encoding="UTF-8"/>
            <beanio id="metaDocFormat" mapping="beanio/mapping.xml" streamName="MetaDoc" encoding="UTF-8"/>
            <beanio id="accStatementFormat" mapping="beanio/mapping.xml" streamName="AccStatement" encoding="UTF-8"/>
            <beanio id="advanceReport" mapping="beanio/mapping.xml" streamName="AdvanceReport" encoding="UTF-8"/>
        </dataFormats>
    </camelContext>

    <bean id="javaUuidGenerator" class="org.apache.camel.impl.JavaUuidGenerator"/>
</blueprint>
```

Simple registry example.

```
public static SimpleRegistry createRegistry() {
    SimpleRegistry simpleRegistry = new SimpleRegistry();
    simpleRegistry.put("transformerFactory", com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.class);
    simpleRegistry.put("javaUuidGenerator", org.apache.camel.impl.JavaUuidGenerator.class);
    return simpleRegistry;
}

public void createCamelContext() {
    logger.info("Create Camel context");
    simpleRegistry = createRegistry();
    defaultCamelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(simpleRegistry);
}
```